# Connect SQL Server Visual Studio to SpiceWorks SQLite Database Failure

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sqlite, odbc

Windows Server 2012

SQL Server 2014

Visual Studio 2013 Professional

SpiceWorks 7.5.00101 / SQLite 3.7.15.2

I am trying to connect SQL Server / Visual Studio to the SpiceWorks SQLite database so I can make a report showing the currently open tickets and who is assigned to them. This report is for the front desk receptionist so she can refer ticket creators that call in to the right person in IT. We don't want her to be able to see potentially sensitive data within the tickets.

I cannot get the connection to work!

I have tried both the 32 and 64 bit sqlite odbc drivers from here: http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

I use the **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe** to create the **32bit** ODBC DSN using the SQLite3 Driver

I use the **C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe** to create the **64bit** ODBC DSN using the SQLite3 Driver

When I attempt to use the 32bit DSN to create either a Linked Server OR when used in a SQL Report (SSRS) as a DataSource I get this error:

```
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

Which is supposed to mean that I used the wrong odbcad32 to create it - but I didn't (I've recreated this damn thing several times)

When I attempt to use the 64bit DSN I get this error:

```
IM006[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
```

All I can find is a HotFix for this reported error 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/822841/fix-setting-of-connection-attribute-fails-when-you-use-connection-pool

- however when I tried to instal the hotfixes they error saying they cannot determine the version of Data tools.

I have tried this on a Windows Server 2008 where the SpiceWorks software/database is installed, and from our Windows 2012 w/SQL Server 2014 using the fully qualified path "\ \spwrks\c$\Program Files (x86)\Spiceworks\db\spiceworks_prod.db" and get the same results.

I have tried pointing to the production database and to a copy of the database.
I have tried to uninstall all of the SQLite drivers and start from scratch. When the 32bit one fails, I uninstall, reboot, and install the 64bit one and it fails.

A very weird part to this is if I create a Server Explorer > Data Connection inside of Visual Studio 2013 pointing to the 32bit DSN , I can see all of the tables, create and execute a query against it without any problems.

Once I publish (deploy) the SSRS report and try it from the browser I get the " The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" error inside the browser.

This is driving me nuts. Help!

I have tried following the instructions on these links:
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/128624-export-spiceworks-sqlite-data-to-ms-sql

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2271-create-ms-sql-linked-server-to-the-spiceworks-sqlite-server

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/28362-view-the-spiceworks-database-and-create-sql-reports

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/132253-how-do-i-generate-a-spiceworks-report-using-sql-server-2008-reporting-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After assistance from Robert with Microsoft, the solution was to disable the **Run64BitRuntime** option under the Property Page for the SSIS Project (right-click on the Project, select Properties, then under Configuration Properties > Debugging, set Run64BitRuntime to False) , because the SQLite is 32bit.

[image]

More information can be found here:
http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20run%20SSIS%20Packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just an update

I have made a SSIS Import job that first copies the existing SQLite database, so I don't mess with the production, then imports the two tables I need (tickets and users) into the 2014 SQL Server. Then, I want to run a report off of those tables.

It seemed to work when I ran the job inside of Visual Studio, but once I tried to schedule the job with SQL Agent it failed to connect to the ODBC. Which made me think of a permission problem since running it inside the SSIS works. I went back to the SpiceWorks folder and database and set permissions to Full Control for Everyone just to see, but it still doesn't want to connect.

As, I have been trying to get it to work; just an hour ago, my production and copied SpiceWorks database became corrupted - not sure if copying it made it happen or what. The whole thing is very... "finicky". I wasn't writing anything to it, just trying to connect and do 2 simple SELECT statements.

Luckily, I had backup copies of the SpiceWorks database and was able to restore it.

I've never had so much trouble just trying to get data from a database!